# convert nested dictionary json response to df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am receiving a nested dictionary as a response to an API call. I tried converting it into a dataframe but I am not able to get the output I want.

I wrote some code to handle the file, but I have a massive chunk of nested dictionary data in the "items" columns. How do I parse that and create a dataframe from it?

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(response.json())
df.to_csv('file1.csv')
```

This is the csv file I was able to generate:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wg0QqkFmIpv_aUYefbrQxBMz_x4hRWMX/view?usp=share_link (check the items column)

I tried the `json_normalize` and `flatdict` route among the other json/dict to df answers on stackoverflow as well but those did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to have finally in `items`?

Comment: A massive chunk of un-nested data which I cannot seem to turn into rows.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
df=df.explode('items')
mask=pd.json_normalize(df.pop('items'))
df=df.join(mask)
```

There are two columns left to convert.

```
print(df[['tags','productConfiguration.allowedOrderQuantities']])
'''
    tags                 productConfiguration.allowedOrderQuantities
0  [popular, onsale]     []
0  [popular, onsale]     []
0  [popular, onsale]     []
0  [popular, onsale]     []
'''
```

explode this to the new rows:

```
df=df.explode('tags').explode('productConfiguration.allowedOrderQuantities').drop_duplicates()
```

but there is a situation. After this operation we have 2 new rows. This means that each row will be repeated 2 times. If there are 100 rows in the dataset there will now be 200 rows because we have converted the json strings into columns and rows.

For a more general explode method:

```
explode_cols=[]
for i in df.columns:
    if type(df[i][0])==list:  #check column value is a list or not ?
        exploded_cols.append(i) # if type is list append column name to explode_cols
        
df=df.explode(explode_cols) #explode df with given column list.
```

Comment: This works when I know which column i need to use `df.explode` on. Is there a more generalized method that would un-nest any form of nested json without me having to specifiy which column to `explode()`

Comment: Yes. I've added a method to my answer where you can do this.